# Should I use "didn't" or "hadn't" in the following case?

Tags: past-vs-past-perfect

This is past-tense narrative:

> Since the violin didn't fit his backpack, he'd been carrying it on his
>   shoulder the whole morning.
>
> Since the violin hadn't fit his backpack, he'd been carrying it on his
>   shoulder the whole morning.

Which version is the correct one? And why?

Comment: Is there a reason you made fit into fitted in the second sentence?

Comment: Catija, The dress fitted her completely  (entry #9 Dictionary.com).

Comment: @Khan but the regular past tense of "fit" is "fit". It is completely unnecessary to use "fitted". The one example I can think of off hand is when describing a piece of clothing "a fitted bodice". It's not wrong but it's not a normal use.

Comment: Okay I changed "fitted" to "fit".

Answer (score 2):

I think there's no point using the past perfect and the past perfect continuous in the sentence. You can rephrase it in the past simple as follows:

Since the violin didn't fit his backpack, he carried (or was carrying) it on his shoulder the whole morning.

Comment: Even in past-tense narration? I often get confused about this. Example: "John set the violin on the stool next to him.
Since it didn't fit his backpack, he carried it on his
shoulder the whole morning."

Comment: @alexchenco *Fit* in these sentences is used as a stative verb; it doesn't designate an event (as it would in *John fit the violin into his pack*) but an enduring characteristic. Consequently the "not fitting" and the "carrying" happen at the same time, and there is no prior event for a perfect to bring in.

Answer (score -1):

In my dialect, the past participle of intransitive 'to fit' is 'fit'.

To fit (intransitive):  to be of appropriate size, as in "The shoe fits".

**The shirt had fit well until it was put in the clothes dryer on high heat.**

The past participle of transitive fit is 'fitted'.

To fit: (transitive): to install something onto something else, as in

**We had not yet fitted the roof with rain gutters and a downspout when it began to rain.**

Comment: **Fit** is a weird verb (the meaning 'to be of appropriate size' does not support a passive form: "*His foot was fit by the shoe.") so please explain the downvote if you understand this verb, because I find it rather  mysterious.

Comment: OP's question is about past simple vs past perfect. Your answer addresses transitive/intransitive usage.

Comment: We understand his question differently. And I'm also addressing the past-perfect form in my answer.